# green apple esters recipes

Tags: recipe, off-flavor

So I was kindly given a Mr. Beer Kit recently. The gifter knew I brewed. I made it per the instructions (except I added honey in the wort to up the gravity a bit). It fermented a bit warm, and it came out with what was a very notable green apple ester flavor.

I'm actually pretty happy to have learned what that actually tastes like on a batch I don't care about. Unfortunately, Now I'm stuck with 7.5L of esterey beer.

Does anyone know of any recipes that might take a vaguely unpleasant drink (I finished a glass, it wasn't as bad as a commercial macro brew) with strong green apple flavor and turn it into a tasty food item?

So far I'm going to try bread and a vinaigrette with a boiled down small bit of the beer.

Comment: Carbonade (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonade_flamande) is a very tasty beef stew cooked in beer.

Comment: Now we're talking. That sounds beautiful.

Comment: I don't think the acetaldehyde will come through in any cooking, and I believe that alothough it is miscible with ethanol and alcohol, that a significant amount will volatilize and evaporate, and any remaining amount will be imperceptible in food. So I would try any recipe that works well with your style of beer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try krausening and aging. Make 1 l of wort of the same OG, pitch with yeast, keep at 18-20C, then on the 2-3rd day pour it to the main batch. Leave for a month there, observing the temperature conditions. Chances are high that the beer will turn drinkable.

Otherwise, find a friend who is into distilling (makes moonshine).

Comment: I don't think you understood my question... The beer is already bottled. I just want food recipes that might taste good with faulty beer

Comment: Well if aging for a month is still not an option, I'd really just give it away to some distiller guy.